# What is the difference between "he dodged behind the wall" and "he ducked behind the wall"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

What is the difference between "he dodged behind the wall" and "he ducked behind the wall"?

[image]

This is what I understand but I am not sure.

"**he dodged behind the wall**" implies that in the beginning, he was standing next to or near the wall then he jumped to the left so that he was behind the wall to void the bullets.

"**he ducked behind the wall**" implies that in the beginning, he was behind the wall but his head was higher than the wall and when the bullets were coming, he lowered his head to avoid the bullets.

**Is that correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

To *dodge* is to move quickly, usually to avoid something.

To *duck* is to lower your body, usually to avoid being seen. He could have bent his knees instead of bending his neck as your diagram indicates.

Answer (score 0):

I would say dodged is relevant in both. He cannot duck behind the wall if he is away from it. But. Ducked is more correct if he is standing and I mean standing behind the wall.

Comment: If someone were near, but not behind, a wall, and they moved behind it quickly, lowering themselves so as not to be  seen, I would happily agree that they 'ducked behind the wall'.